# why doesn't *.abc match a file named .abc?

Tags: macos, git, wildcard

I thought I understood wildcards, till this happened to me. Essentially, I'm looking for a wild card pattern that would return all files that are not named `.gitignore`. I came up with this, which seems to work for all cases I could conjure:

```
ls *[!{gitignore}]
```

To really validate if this works, I thought I'd negate the expression and see if it returns the file named `.gitignore` (actually any file that ended with `gitignore`; so `1.gitignore` should also be returned). To that effect, I thought the negated expression would be:

```
ls *[{gitignore}]
```

However, this expression doesn't return a files named `.gitignore` (although it returns a file named `1.gitignore`).

Essentially, my question, after simplification, boils down to:

> Why doesn't *.abc match a file that is named .abc

I think I can take it from there.

PS:

1. I am working on Mac OSX Lion (10.7.4)
2. I wanted to add a clause to `.gitignore` such that I would ignore every file, except `.gitignore` in a given folder. So I ended up adding `*` in the `.gitignore` file. Result was, git ended up ignoring `.gitignore` :)
3. From the numerous searches I've made on google - `Use the asterisk character (*) to represent zero or more characters.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using Bash. From the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘.’ at the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set.

[.gitignore](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.html) patterns, however, are treated differently:

> Otherwise, git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname.

According to the [fnmatch(3) docs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch), a leading dot has to be explicitly matched only if the `FNM_PERIOD` flag is set, so `*gitignore` as a gitignore pattern would match `.gitignore`.

There is an easier way to accomplish this, though. To have `.gitignore` ignore everything except `.gitignore`:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. A google on `dotglob` came up with this statement `bash doesn't glob dot-files` which, I think explains it all. Thanks a bunch, you're the man! And  yes, I'm using a bash shell (sorry I forgot to mention).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore everything *except* the `gitignore` file, use this as the file:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Lines starting with an exclamation point are interpreted as exceptions.